# How do I print out only log messages for a given logger?

Tags: python, logging, python-2.7

Currently I am doing this in my code:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info("something happened")
```

Then at the top of my main scripts I do this:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

Problem is that there are too many messages. Is there any way to restrict it to one or a few different loggers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control individual loggers by name. (In your example, you used **name**, which will be the module name, so each logger will have a different name, module by module). You can use the logging config file to control the logging level of each logger individually. Have a look at the PEP:
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0282/